# Close a txt file opened by another process in Windows programmatically

Tags: java, python, c, vba, winapi

I am looking to force close a txt file that is opened by another process. Looking for suggestions, ideas on how this can be accomplished, and the caveats involved.

Python solution would be great, however other programming languages are fine as well. I am able to list the process, and how many files that are opened by that process, but going blank on how to close that file.

Comment: Depends on the process. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, killing process by name using Python:

```py
    import sys, traceback, os

    def py_kill (process_name):
        try:
            killed = os.system('tskill ' + process_name)
        except Exception, e:
            killed = 0
        return killed
```

You can call it like this:

```py
py_kill("program_name")
```

Kill process by PID using C#:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    namespace killprocess
    {
       class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             if(args.Length!=1)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(“Argument is required: Process ID to kill”);
                return;
             }
             Regex regex = new Regex(“^[0-9]+$”);
             bool bb = regex.IsMatch(args[0]);
             if (!bb)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(“Process Id should be prositive integer”);
                return;
             }
             int pid = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
             try
             {
             nbsp;  Process process2Kill = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                process2Kill.Kill();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format(“Process with ID {0} has been terminated”, pid));
             } catch (Exception ex)
             {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
             ;}
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What if I have multiple documents open by multiple different process, all backed by the same executable?

Comment: I don't understand why the negative vote, he is asking to close a file text opened by a process, those codes can get the job done. Your escenario is plausible, in that case We can stop the process tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without killing the other process, you need to use `NtQueryInformationProcess` to get a list of `HANDLE` opened by the process. You can also use `NtQuerySystemInformation` to get global list of opened `HANDLE`. It's then a matter of then just closing the `HANDLE` using `NtDuplicateObject.`

See: https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/WindowsNT-Handle-Scanner/blob/master/FindHandles/main.cpp

Comment: But the target process might fail after doing that, since it still uses a closed handle (or creates a new handle with the same value, which could be worse).

Comment: It is the only way. If Windows itself close the handle, the process will also get `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` error.

Comment: Yes, it may be the only way. But that doesn't mean it's safe to do so.

Comment: It seems though this is only way, unless there is something I don’t know yet.